# limit on the number of instances of a program that can run simultaneously

Tags: fedora, process, libsvm

In linux ( fedora ) , is there any limit on the number of instances of the same program that can be run simultaneously ? I am using libsvm , and want to run ./svm-train simultaneously for  9 different files < in 9 different terminals > .. Will this cause any problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit will be, most likely, memory. SVM training uses a lot. If you run many, you will thrash unless you have a large quantity of RAM.

Comment: oh , the system has 1 GB RAM , and it took me more than 12 hours when i ran 4 instances simultaneously .. Will it have taken lesser time if i had run one process at a time ?

Comment: How much memory was in use ? if > 1Gb, yes you would get significant speedup. If < 1Gb, no speedup. Also, you will likely not get any speedup if you run nr of instances > nr of processors

Comment: is it possible to find the memory used ? How to do that..

Comment: You can get an idea how much memory each process uses with htop or top, but multiple instances of the same program will add up to a falsely high number because they're using the same instance of libraries.  It would be pretty simple to just watch swapping using top and see whether your RAM is overloaded.

Comment: Training a discriminative model like an SVM involves a gigantic quantity of data.